# How can colour be added manually in ggplot and legend labels renamed in the same plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
p <- ggplot(mpg, aes(x= displ, y= hwy, fill = drv)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("forestgreen", "blue", "deepred"))
```

When I add following code to change legend labels:

```
p + scale_fill_discrete(labels = c("4wd", "front", " rear"))
```

**I get this error warning:**

> Scale for 'fill' is already present. Adding another scale for 'fill',
>   which will replace the existing scale.

So it replaces the existing scale and returns to first scale. How can it be prevented?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to provide values and labels at the same time.

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mpg, aes(x= displ, y= hwy, fill = drv)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = c("forestgreen", "blue", "darkred"),
    labels = c("4wd", "front", " rear")
  )
```

[image]

If for some reason you have a plot with scale and want to update the scale, that's fine also, but again you need to set all the parameters you require at once.

```r
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(mpg, aes(x= displ, y= hwy, fill = drv)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = c("forestgreen", "blue", "darkred")
  )

p + scale_fill_manual(
  values = c("forestgreen", "blue", "darkred"),
  labels = c("4wd", "front", " rear")
)
#> Scale for 'fill' is already present. Adding another scale for 'fill',
#> which will replace the existing scale.
```

[image]